# Sending a variable from a PHP file to another PHP file

Tags: php

This is a simplified version of a project I'm working on.

The main idea is that test.php sends 'acct-id' to submitData.php and it validates if the account ID already exists in the server. In case it already exists, I want to send an error message to test.php.

I have built this code but I can't get '$err_msg' to change it's value in test.php. This variable changes it's value within the 'while' loop but it does not change outside it.

How can I send $err_msg value to test.php?

Thanks in advance to all possible help.

**test.php**

```
<?php
include 'submitData.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="submitData.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="acct-id">
        <input type="submit" name="submit-btn">
        <?=$err_msg?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**submitData.php**

```
<?php
include '../tools/db_config.php';
$err_msg = "test";

if(isset($_POST["submit-btn"])){
    $acct_id = $_POST["acct-id"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE acct_id='$acct_id'";
    if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ){
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $err_msg = "This account already exists.";
            }
            header('Location: test.php');
        }
    }else {
            $output="Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Session for this.

```
<?php
include '../tools/db_config.php';
session_start();
$err_msg = "test";
if(isset($_POST["submit-btn"])){
    $acct_id = $_POST["acct-id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE acct_id='$acct_id'";
    if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ){
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $err_msg = "This account already exists.";
            }
            $_SESSION['err_msg']     = $err_msg;
            header('Location: test.php');
        }
    }else {

            $output="Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
    }
}

?
```

> 

```
<?php
include 'submitData.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="submitData.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="acct-id">
        <input type="submit" name="submit-btn">
        <?=$_SESSION['err_msg']?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```